# Set th:value in Thymeleaf date input?

Tags: html, datepicker, thymeleaf, default-value

I use Thymeleaf and I want to show the user the **existing** date value before they edit it, and also in case they don't want to edit it they can just leave it as is. I've been trying to set a date input value but it's not working.

What I tried:

Artist:

```
private Date dateDebut;
```

Controller:

```
String dateDebut = Artist.getDateDebut().toString();
model.addAttribute("dateDebut", dateDebut);
```

View:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateDebut" th:value="${dateDebut}" />
```

However this doesn't work. It still shows me the date input like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdZIw.png instead of the set value that I'm trying to show.

I have tried using Bootstrap datepicker but it didn't work either. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If you use `type="date"`, then the browser gets to choose the format of the date.  If you want to format it yourself, you have to use `type="text"`.
2. `th:value="${dateDebut}"` won't respect your `@DateTimeFormat` annotation.  If you want thymeleaf to output in that format you should either use use [double-brace](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#data-conversion-formatting) syntax -- `th:value="${{dateDebut}}"` for example -- or use `th:field` instead (which would mean other changes). The former is probably better in this case.

Edit:

If you want to use `type="date"`, keep the annotation `@DateTimeFormat (pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")` and use double-brace:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateDebut" th:value="${{dateDebut}}" />
```

Alternatively, you can use the date formatting functions:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateDebut" th:value="${#dates.format(dateDebut, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! However my problem is not only the format but also **setting a value of the input** to show before editting. I don't mind the format because as you said it depends on the browser, and the app I'm developing will be used on French browsers so the date format will be "dd-mm-yyyy" by default. I just added **@DateTimeFormat** because I thought it would help with saving to database (I'm guessing I was wrong). Your suggestion to use **type="text"** works but if I do that I don't get the visual of the calendar which I'd like to use if possible~ I will edit my question

Comment: Thanks! 2nd suggestion with date formatting functions worked. 
(for any future readers) I also had to add dateDebut.substring(0, 10).replace('-', '/') in controller before sending to view, otherwise it was giving me a ConversionFailedException from String to Date